# Do the formal proof and find the derived lines there should be 8 or 9 lines with these formal proofs

Tags: logic

1. W>X
2. (W•X)>Y
3. (W•Y)>Z therefore W>Z
4. 5. X>(W•Y) 2,5,H.S
5. X>Z 6,3,H.S
6. W>Z 1,7,H.S.

I don’t know what to do next please help thank you

Comment: Do you have Conditional Proof as one of your rules?

Comment: No I do not have that

Comment: Yikes ... so what rules *do* you have?  Can you please list them in your Post? Thanks!

Comment: I have modus ponens

Comment: You'll need a lot more than H.S. and Modus Ponens to complete this one ... What book are you using?

Comment: Modus Tollens, hypothetical syllogism, disjunctive syllogism, constructive dilemma, absorption, simplification, conjunction and addition

Comment: If you add Conditional proof to those you'd be all set ... sure you don't have that one? Sounds like you have Copi or Hurley ... It may be listed separately as C.P.

Comment: Sorry by accident I pushed enter when I wasn’t done typing the rest of the rules

Comment: Yes I have Copi but he doesn’t use c.p in this book only the 9 rules I stated

Comment: Hmm .. then I am guessing there are a bunch of equivalence principles as well ... such as Commutation, Association, Distribution, Implication, .... do you see those?

Comment: No, I have absorption that might help with this problem

Comment: Oh, right, that strange Absorption rule from Copi .. that rings a bell ...  how is that defined again in Copi?

Comment: p>q therefore p>(p•q)

Comment: Ah, right!  Strange rule, but it's his way of avoiding Conditional proof. OK, so yes, Absorption is key.

Comment: yes and i think hypothetical syllogism  should help as well

Comment: You bet. In fact, see my Answer below: those two will do it :)

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Absorption is key:

\begin{array}{lll}
1&W \to X&Assumption\\
2&(W \land X) \to Y& Assumption\\
3&(W \land Y) \to Z& Assumption\\
4&W \to (W \land X) & Absorption \ 1\\
5& W \to Y & H.S. \ 2,4\\
6& W \to (W \land Y) & Absorption \ 5\\
7& W \to Z & H.S. \ 3,6\\
\end{array}

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: @TaylorWatson You're welcome! :)